# I'm trying to solve a React syntax ERROR, but nothing is working

Tags: reactjs

My App.js code is reciving the error: ./src/App.js SyntaxError: C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\bd\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (19:15)    17 |   return (   18 |     // variavel  - componente > 19 |     {character ?  : P  ```

```
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';
import characterCard from './components/characterCard';

function App() {

  const [character, setCharacter] = useState ({});
  const [name, setName] = useState ('Walter+White');

  async function getCharacter(){
    const [character] = await (await fetch(`https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters?name=${name}`)).json();
    console.log(character);
    setName(character);
  }

  return (
    
    {character ? <characterCard character = {character}/> : <button onClick = {getCharacter}>Procurar personagem</button>}

  )
};

  
export default App;
```

And i have here my index.js

```
function characterCard({character}){



    return (<h1>{character.name}</h1>);

}

export default characterCard;
```

SOMEONE COULD HELP ME PLEASE?

Comment: If you get rid of all the empty lines and redundant whitespace it makes it a bit easier to read for others. Btw, component names, e.g. `characterCard` always need to start with a capital letter. That's how JSX distinguishes components from built-in elements like `div`.

Comment: Its probably because of `{ character? <... }` line. Wrap it. ie `<>{character ? < ..... </>`

Answer (score 2):

In order to use React syntax (XML in JS), you have to have 'React' imported in every component using the syntax:

`import React from 'react';`

In your case, since you're also importing `useState()`, modify the import statement to:

`import React, {useState} from 'react';`

This would work granted that you've configured your project to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). If you're new to all this and just want to get started with learning React, try [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Comment: This is no longer true, depending on what version of React you use: [Introducing the New JSX Transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)